# How to check the connectivity of an endpoint before sending requests in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am a bit new to spring boot.

I am asking if there is a way through which I can check if a particular endpoint is alive before sending any requests in spring boot.

Let's say I have an endpoint like 172.XX.XX.XX:1010/api/xxx/ and I want to check if that endpoint is alive before I send any request to it. Is there any way to that?

I am using spring boot.

Comment: Did you checked Rest Assured? it can be integrated with spring and response code can be checked in single line

Comment: What benefit are you hoping for by checking? You may be better just making the request and handling an error. Even if the check, making a HEAD request for example, succeeds, there’s no guarantee that a subsequent GET request won’t fail as the endpoint could have gone down in between the two.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [spring boot actuator](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators) health check endpoint to check if your service is online, but in terms of checking if a particular endpoint is 'alive' you may as well just make the request as if the service is alive then you will be able to make the call to the endpoint

Answer (score 0):

I don't think checking if an API endpoint exists before firing the actual call is beneficial. In the best case scenario, you will be making 2 api calls rather than one. Sure, for GET requests, you can fire a HEAD request first, but it doesn't seem to be worth it. Instead, you can have handlings in your client code based on the response code from the API (40x, 50x).